# how to get stripe dashboard data(net volume, spend per customer etc..) using Stripe API in Node.js(attaching picture for reference)

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

[stripe dashboard image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odZUK.jpg)

I want to get some details that is showing in stripe dashboard using stripe API but I only able to get total sales.
can anybody tell me how to get total sales using 2 different dates and other things also.

Answer (score 0):

Stripi documentation could be helpful in this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/reports/api);

```
// Timestamps are for 2020-01-01 00:00 PST and 2020-02-01 00:00 PST.
// The columns parameter is optional. A default set of columns will be provided if you don't specify a value.

const reportRun = await stripe.reporting.reportRuns.create({
  report_type: 'Report Type/Name',
  parameters: {
    interval_start: '1577865600',
    interval_end: '1580544000',
    timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles',
    columns: ['created', 'reporting_category', 'net'],
  },
});
```